# ScrollView top part is cut off when I added adjustPan so keyboard won't overlap EditText

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-scrollview

I have a ScrollView (with a RecyclerView inside) and a RelativeLayout after it which contains EditText. I added

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

for the activity in my manifest file because my keyboard overlaps the EditText but in effect, whenever the keyboard is active, the top part of my ScrollView is cut off.

I have tried using `NestedScrollView` and setting `RelativeLayout` `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_gravity="center"` but that doesn't work. Below is the snippet of my code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/news_comments"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_title">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/individual_news_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            // some other layouts

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/individual_news_item"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_message_actions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_send_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <github.ankushsachdeva.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_message_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:hint="@string/keyMessage"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/light_black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/zipt"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                emojicon:emojiconSize="18sp" />

            <ImageButton />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

any ideas how i can solve this?

Comment: Use adjustResize instaed of adjustPan in manifest.

Comment: That doesn't fix the keyboard overlap in my case.

Comment: can u provide a screenshot of your design